# Custom object detection in the browser using TensorFlow.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, browser, tensorflow.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPYLN.png)

I trained my сustom object detection in tensorflow 2 and got file format saved_model.pb after for object detection in the browser using TensorFlow Convertor and got file format model.json but i have problem with my  model

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.